How do provide user input when installing a package using pip in notebook
I have created a notebook in Microsoft Fabric. I am trying to install a package. The installation process is asking for user input. However, I can't find a way to provide the answer.
The command I am using is !conda install -c conda-forge poppler. While installing, the process is asking for a yes or no answer.


is there a non-conda source you can use for these items that you can install via pip? Or install on the cluster and not the notebook level?

! just runs a bash command, so
!conda install -c conda-forge poppler <<< y
or the %conda magic will handle this for you, and install the package on any additional worker nodes.
%conda install -c conda-forge poppler 
